# ElasticSearch / Node : delete items by match

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to delete only the indexes with  "datastorage.clientID" : "00001" but it deletes all the items, do you see any error in this code?

```
deleteAllByClientID: function (clientID,callback) {
        console.log("clientID" , clientID)
        client.indices.delete({ 
            index: 'datastorage',
            body: {
                query: {
                    "match" : {
                        "datastorage.clientID" : clientID
                    }
                }
            }
        }, function (err, res) {
            callback(err, res);
        });

    }
```

the delete function above **returns { acknowledged: true }**

Please consider that this search function works fine

```
GetItems: function (clientID,callback) {

        client.search({
            index: 'datastorage',
            scroll : "1m", 
            size:10000,
            body: {
                query: {
                        "match" : {
                            "datastorage.clientID" : clientID
                        }
                }
            }
        }, function (err, resp, status) {
            callback(err,resp);
        });
    },
```

Thanks Andrea

Comment: Do you want to delete documents or indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deleting documents matching a query, you should use the [Delete By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html). With the Javascript client you should call the client.deleteByQuery method (see [client documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_deletebyquery)). In your case this would look like this:

```
deleteAllByClientID: function (clientID,callback) {
        console.log("clientID" , clientID)
        client.deleteByQuery({ 
            index: 'datastorage',
            body: {
                query: {
                    "match" : {
                        "datastorage.clientID" : clientID
                    }
                }
            }
        }, function (err, res) {
            callback(err, res);
        });

    }
```